# Take time left in the current day by moment

Tags: momentjs

I want something like this

```js
moment().endOf('day').fromNow().milliseconds();
```

someone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and subtract current date from end of day. Difference is in milliseconds

```js
var result = moment().endOf('day').diff(moment())

console.log(result, moment(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```